# How do gravitons escape each other's gravity to spread out and form a field?

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles

The hypothetical graviton I'm familiar with is a spin-2 particle.  That implies it has angular momentum, which further implies it has energy.  If energy attracts energy, what prevents gravitons from clumping together? How do gravitons escape each other's gravity to spread out and form a field?

Comment: I think that you are mixing up the concept of field in classical physics, (gravitational field, electric field, magnetif field, ) and the fields of quantum field theory.  There are no gravitons in classical physics. The gravitons are  for a quantization of gravity (not yet definitive) the analogue of photons for the quantizations of the electromagnetic field.

Comment: This is a similar question to what happens to the gluons of QCD, since they too attract each other. The answer as far as we can tell is that they in fact clump together into so called "glueballs". These glueballs have mass, associated with the binding energy that keeps these gluons bound together. The answer in the case of gravity is not clear.

Comment: Anna v, no one said there are gravitons in classical physics, but it is alleged that if a gravitational field is quantized, that would lead to gravitons.

Comment: Fewfewd, indeed the answer is not clear in the case of gravity.  Thanks for your response.